# Как составить таблицу с заданными ключами из результата функции?

Tags: lua

В lua функция может вернуть несколько значений и их можно легко присвоить переменным вот таким образом:

```
function test()
  return "first", "second", "third"
end

local one, two, three = test()

print(two) -- "second"
```

Мне нужно составить таблицу из результата такой функции. Я могу сделать это, обернув её фигурными скобками:

```
local t = {test()} 

print(t[2]) -- "second"
```

Но в таком случае таблица будет массивом, а мне нужно чтобы она была объектом. Т.е. мне нужно указать ключи для значений:

```
local t = {one, two, three = test()}

print(t.two) -- nil :(
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать и почему мой вариант не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое присвоение делается достаточно просто:

```
local t = {}
t.one, t.two, t.three = test()
```

В таблицах ведь можно динамически добавлять/удалять ключи.

А ваш вариант не сработал, потому что в конструкторе таблицы каждому ключу надо задавать его значение индивидуально. Там множественное присвоение не работает. Т.е. вы объявили два не инициализированных ключа и один ключ инициализированный первым значением результата функции `test()` (остальные значения той функции были отброшены).

Comment: Таким методом я и пользовался, у меня было примерно так: `app.window.w, app.window.h, app.window.flags = love.window.getMode()` Мне здесь не нравится  постоянное повторение "app.window", хотелось бы как-то лаконичнее записать, но наверное это я придираюсь к мелочам.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Можно сделать так: `local t = app.window` и далее по тексту вместо `app.window` обращаться к `t`. При этом `t` будет ссылкой на таблицу `app.window`, а не её копией.

Comment: Вот эти нюансы насчёт ссылок и копий я ещё не изучал, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не работает, потому что на самом деле происходит инициализация таблицы 5 элементами:

```
local t = {one, two, three = "1", "2", "3"} -- не 3, а 5! 

print(t.three) -- только тут ключ получает значение "1"
print(t[3]) -- это "2"  и т.д.
```

Выход - возвращать сразу таблицу:

```
function test()
  return { one="first", two="second", three ="third" }
end
```

или  вот такой 2 вариант:

```
function test()
  return "first", "second", "third"
end

local t ={}
for k, v in pairs({test()}) do    t[v] = v    end

print (t.first)
print (t.second)
print (t.third)
```

Comment: Очень странное поведение. Не понимаю, почему именно 5 и почему в таком порядке? По поводу возвращения сразу таблицы - этот вариант мне не подходит. Функция не моя, у меня есть только её результат, который нужно обработать, я не могу в ней ничего менять.

Comment: 5, потому что  через запятую все они 5 и перечислены, но при этом #t будет =4 , потому что как только в массив закралось ключ=значение, то это уже не обычный массив, а просто таблица - и порядок элементов будет не предсказуем.

Comment: добавил в ответ другой вариант

Comment: Если честно, я задал этот вопрос в надежде на то, что в языке присутствует какой-то более простой и элегантный способ создания key-value таблицы из одного списка с ключами и другого списка со значениями, но видимо его нет. Придётся использовать вспомогательную функцию. Спасибо.

Comment: сократил немного вариант, так даже проще выглядит..

Comment: @MikeV. Ваш код делает весьма странную штуку - в качестве ключа подставляет значение. Представьте, что в качестве значений функция `test` возвращает 3 таблицы, а не просто строки. И куда это вас заведёт?

Comment: @zed зачем представлять то, чего нет? и конечно, если бы в условии были таблицы, то и решение было бы другим.